# LiveUSB not showing HDD when installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows-10

I bought this nice, light and portable Acer e11-132 with 32gb HD, 4gb of RAM, windows 10. I've created a Ubuntu liveUSB using rufus as I usually do and despite doing research I can't seem to find a way to make the liveUSB detect the hard drive so I can install it Ubuntu.

I've updated the BIOS to see if it gives me any new options but nothing. When I "try Ubuntu" from the liveUSB and -l disks on the terminal it only shows the USB itself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `lsblk` to see whether it is recognizing disc but unable to read/mount it. In your liveCD, open the terminal, and run: `sudo apt install gparted` to install the `GParted` program that is useful for creating and managing partitions. Open GParted through the applications menu/Unity search box and see if it can detect your HDD under the _Devices_ tab.

Comment: @Aalok Thank you, `lsblk` and Gparted show the liveUSB only. It doesn't recognize the HDD. I've been googling but no luck.

Comment: When it first shipped with Windows on it, were you able to boot Windows? This might not be convenient, but if possible for you, I would ask you to try it before seeking hardware maintenance support: try booting a Windows LiveCD and then see if you can spot your HDD.

Comment: I bought it from a second hand shop. I tried to use a Windows LiveUSB and it didn't work, it does work with a Ubuntu LiveUSB but the eMMC drive can't be detected. It's really frustrating, I disabled ''Secure boot'' on BIOS but it seems this BIOS doesn't have a way to change the ''Boot mode'', I have the latest version of the BIOS.